# Changing UIKit Item Appearance in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios5

I am using iOS 5 and changing the color of the UIBarButton by using this code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:120/255.0 blue:181/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

I want them to be another color in some views though (1 color in navbar, 1 color when in toolbar).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can use the [`+appearanceWhenContainedIn:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn%3a) method:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:...];
```

That way the tint color of `UIBarButtonItems` will only be affected when they're embedded inside a `UINavigationBar`.